# Uploading an image to a site via their API

Tags: vb.net, image, post, memorystream, uploading

I have a bot running in an online game which the staff use to draw out the map's levels. It uploads these pics to Imgur using its API, but Imgur isn't always up and running so I'd like to add a 2nd host as a backup plan.

I discovered this site which looks like a fine choice: https://boring.host/api

To get an API key, sign up (fast, no confirmation needed) then go to "My Account" by clicking your name on the top right.

Looking at the API info, it looks like I just need to send a HTTP POST to "https://api.boring.host/api/v1/upload" and include the "api_token" and "file" parameters.

When I upload to Imgur, I write the image to a MemoryStream then convert that to a Base64String:

```vb
Convert.ToBase64String(bytImage)
```

So I tried the same thing for this:

```vb
    Public Function UploadBoringHost(Dim bm as Bitmap) As String
        'Write image to memorystream
        Dim bytImage As Byte()
        Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            bm.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            bytImage = stream.ToArray
        End Using

        'Upload
        Using client As New WebClient
            Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
            reqparm.Add("api_token", strApiKey)
            reqparm.Add("file", Convert.ToBase64String(bytImage))
            Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues("https://api.boring.host/api/v1/upload", "POST", reqparm)
            Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
        End Using
    End Function
```

Trying it this way, I get the following web exception: "The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity"

My only guess is that it's expecting the image data to be passed through in some other format. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that you're supposed to post a JSON. What the JSON should contain is not well defined. That site doesn't provide any meaningful insight on the format it expects. If the API is actually working. Try to email the owner.

Comment: I think that you have your data right.  [This](https://gist.github.com/six519/5ed917850f402b94ee6b) may be useful in converting it to JSON to post.